# Use the WSO2 application server for deploy application with hibernate spring framework

Tags: spring, hibernate, wso2

I want to develop spring (3.1.2) and hibernate (3.6.4) application and deploy it in WSO2 application (5.2.1) server.
I tried it as service such as the spring service and the AAR service,but unfortunately all of them couldn't persist an object in data base.I encountered with differents bugs such as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" and..., I found out the problem, caused by jar files in my project and inconsistency with WSO2 lib. After I add my lib in WSO2 lib folders the problems are persisted. Do you have any hint?

Comment: when posting questions, providing the actual error helps to identify the issue!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably want to deploy your application as a webapp. By deploying it as a webapp, you can avoid the incompatibility of libs between wso2 and your application. You can see some spring related samples in AS_HOME/samples/Jaxws-Jaxrs.

By default, webapps do not see the org.springframework.* packages that are available in wso2 repository/components/plugins folder. This is configurable. You might probably want to read this all in one docuementation on [wso2 webapp classloading](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AS521/Webapp+ClassLoading).

Comment: I want to publish some services in this application, if i deploy it is webapp , how can I expose my services? please give me your advice about select type of application?

Comment: if you want to expose it as a SOAP service, then you can write a JAX-WS service that can be deployed as a webapp. The sample location I have provided contains a set of samples for both JAX-WS and JAX-RS (REST services)